# Parameterize default netbeans project name

Tags: netbeans

I have multiple versions of a single project in one project group.  When I open the project in netbeans I want the projects view to show the projects named by the directory they're in.
So if I checkout projectX as projectX-1.2 that will be the name of the project parent directory AND the name of the project display name.

But what happens is the project display name is whatever is hardcoded in project.xml.

If I rename the project (right-click, select rename from the dropdown), netbeans will change the display name, but it will also change the deployment names - so if projectX creates projectX.war, renaming it to projectX-1.2 changes the war name to projectX1.2.war.

I can manually rename the project display by hand-editing project.xml
projectX-1.2
But what I'd like to do is set it to 
${whatever-parent-directory-name-is}
So it doesn't have to be done manually won't contaminate anyone else's working copy.

Is there a way to set this when creating a new project?

I'm using netbeans 8.0

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for your problem is to use **version control tool** to manage the different versions of your project. Use version control system like GIT (with github.com as reposotory for instance)  or SVN.
Those tool are available in NetBeans and other IDEs like Eclipse.
In your case, you need to create different branches for the same project, you can work in each branch separately and then merge them whenever you want. It's also a way to keep the code of your project available online, in case you lose the code locally, it also allows you to work with a team of developers smoothly and remotely. So, I strongly encourage you to go for a version control solution for your development work.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough.  We use SVN to manage our projects.  What happens is I check out trunk/ProjectX and open it in netbeans.  Then I check out branch/ProjectX-release-whatever and open it in netbeans - same project, different revision.  I want to default the project display name in netbeans so it's easy to distinguish between projects.

Comment: If you use a version control like Git (the one that I'm using in Netbeans) normally you have the name of the branch between brackets, after the name of project. For instance **myProject[master]** for one instance of the project (one branch) and **myProject[myProject_Branch1]** for another project instance in the IDE. This way you cannot confuse between them. I don't know if it works the same way for SVN, but it should be similar. I hope this helps.